# How to migrate Azure SQL Server database (data) to kubernetes ms sql database

Tags: sql-server, azure, kubernetes, azure-sql-database, azure-aks

I have data in an Azure SQL Server database and I need to migrate all data with structure to SQL Server kubernetes. What are the approaches we have for that?

Please explain in detail.

Comment: there is no difference, a sql is a sql, doesn't matter where its hosted. so all the normal ways of doing this appy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to migrate a database from Azure SQL Database so some other flavor of SQL Server is to [Export a .bacpac file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export), and [Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-2017) it on the target server.

Comment: I don't want to go the prod down. Can I make it as a replica of current database and switch my secondary database to primary on the fly.

Comment: Currently, no.  You can make a Copy of the production database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy and export and import that.  But you either need to have downtime or some application-level process to bring the imported copy up-to-date.  Azure SQL Data Sync is an automated way to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data